# How to make a UserControl with a custom DefaultBackColor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

When I right-click on my custom UserControl's `BackColor` property in the property-grid, then click Reset, I would like the `BackColor` property to change to (for example) `Color.LightGreen`, and the property value to appear un-bolded, to indicate that it is the default value.

Currently, I know I can do this:

```
public override void ResetBackColor() {
    BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
}
```

Which works as far as setting it to LightGreen on reset. But it still appears **bolded** in the property-grid, indicating that the current value is not the default.

I notice that the `Control` class has a static read-only property, `DefaultBackColor`. Unfortunately, since it's static, I cannot override it.

Is there some way to get all the functionality I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
}

[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "LightGreen")]
public override Color BackColor
{
    get
    {
        return base.BackColor;
    }
    set
    {
        base.BackColor = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: this not work, as he said there is a need to override the static read-only property, DefaultBackColor

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a custom control with a custom backcolor, as you itself mentioned you cannot use porperty defaultbackcolor.

Example in vb.net

```
   <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
    Public Shared Function GetParent(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

   Protected Overrides Sub CreateHandle()
        Dim parentHandle As IntPtr = GetParent(Me.Handle)
        ParentForm = Control.FromHandle(parentHandle)
        ParentForm.TransparencyKey = Me.BackColor
   End Sub
```